# Javascript Merge array changes into original array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, algorithm, merge

I have an array like follows to begin with;

```
[{
    name: 'a',
    color: 'red',
    children: 
    [{
        name: 'a1',
        color: 'red',
        children: 
        [{
            name: 'a11'
        }]
    },
    {
        name: 'a2'
        color: 'red',
    }]
},
{
    name: 'b'
    color: 'red',
}]
```

The user then makes changes on the frontend and I get back the new structure of the array like follows;

```
[{
    name: 'a'
    color: 'red',
    children: 
    [{
        name: 'a1'
        color: 'red',
    },
    {
        name: 'a2'
        color: 'red',
        children: 
        [{
            name: 'a21',
            color: 'yellow'
        }]
    }]
},
{
    name: 'new'
    color: '',
},
{
    name: 'a11'
    color: 'red',
},
{
    name: 'b'
    color: 'red',
}]
```

As you can see, some objects have moved and some have been added. I then need to merge the changes back into the original array, not changing the objects that haven't changed.

This list is rendered by angular, so if I just replace the original array with the new one it will render the whole array again (and this array can be massive) and it causes a slow down.

I tried using merge function in lodash but I then run into problems with the object with name "new" getting a color "red" due to the object with name "b" in the original array already having a color.

Whats the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: You have to do it manually.

Comment: Could you please provide the logic behind the change?

Comment: Can you not push the new objects to the array itself as and when the user adds an item?

Comment: Is the name to be seen as kind of an ID? or can it change? And would this "ID" be unique globally (across the whole datastructure), or just in it's own context (like the Array the object's in)?

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for, is diffing the two datastructures (before and after changes) and rendering only these changes to the DOM.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure - the change is controlled by the user, it is a drag and drop interface.

Comment: @Pavan - The way it currently works is that once an item is moved, an event is fired that is picked up in the angular controller. The controller then makes the change to the structure. This structure is then passed into a directive that does the rendering (and keeps its own copy of the array).

Comment: @Thomas - you can assume there could be a globally unique identifier. Yes I do only want to render the changes to the DOM.

Comment: @Luke, then it should be fairly easy to map the objects by this name, so that you can easily look up wether there was an object my that name in the previous state, and apply only the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has an inbuilt function for this `angular.merge()` which works in `angular 1.6.5` for this kind of scenario. Please check the compatibility with your angular version.

The main line of code is shown below.

```
angular.merge($scope.source, $scope.changed);
```

Here the `$scope.source` is merged with `$scope.changed`, The changes are done to the `$scope.source` directly and there is no need for an `LHS` variable.

I have tried to represent what is going on, in the below fiddle. Please check if this code is able to solve your issue!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: @Luke Does this answer help you?